# Shell into swarm container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm unable to connect to a container that's running on a swarm. Seems like the following doesn't work:

```
docker exec -it <container_ID> bash
```

Here is some output:

```
>$ docker service ls
ID            NAME          REPLICAS  IMAGE                              COMMAND
4rliefwe74o5  login         1/1       login-arm64:1.0


>$ docker service ps login
ID                         NAME     IMAGE                       NODE               DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR
2jk3s2xs7ce62piunbkiptypz  login.1  login-arm64:1.0  odroid64-cluster4  Running        Running 5 minutes ago
```

Then I'll run:

```
$ docker exec -it 2jk3s2xs7ce62piunbkiptypz bash
```

or

```
$ docker exec -it login.1 bash
```

and see the following errors

> Error response from daemon: No such container: 2jk3s2xs7ce62piunbkiptypz

> Error response from daemon: No such container: login.1

Comment: Post the error message, and I suppose it was `bash` and not `bash"`

Comment: Updated the original post. Basically, docker doesn't see these containers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `docker ps` to find the names you can use. Look under both `CONTAINER ID` and `NAMES`, either will work.

```
>$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e53bff8bebfc        login-arm64:1.0   "/bin/sh -c 'node ser"   27 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds                           login.1.cg7fltcu3wfe7ixtnqzg8myy1

>$ docker exec -it e53bff8bebfc bash
root@e53bff8bebfc:/#
```

The long name is of the form `$SERVICE_NAME.$REPLICA_NUMBER.$ID_FROM_SERVICE_PS`

```
>$ docker exec -it login.1.cg7fltcu3wfe7ixtnqzg8myy1 bash
root@e53bff8bebfc:/#
```

Comment: In my case, the long name did not work, but the "container id" does work.

Comment: This is probably obvious to everyone but me, but still, if anyone is dumbed down in the same way, the `docker ps` has to be run on a swarm **worker** node, otherwise on master `docker ps` results to nothing for me, as there are no running containers.

Comment: A minor supplement: If you see the container you want with `docker service ps` but not `docker ps`, check the `NODE` listed by `docker service ps` and log into _that_ host instead of the master node you started with. From there you can use `docker exec` as @sam-myers describes.

Answer (score 11):

Quite an older question, but just my two cents here: I very often run: 
`docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name="login*") sh`
 
`-q` only returns the container id
`-f name="login*"` applies a filter based on container name, using a regex
This comes in handy because starting a new container will change the container name with some random characters in it. It's important that your filter returns just 1 container, so specify the name in a way that there will be just 1 result. For example: if you have a container "monster" and a container "monitor", you need `-f name="moni*"` to exclude the "monster" container.
The command will result in something like:
`docker exec -it login.1.cg7fltcu3wfe7ixtnqzg8myy1 sh`

Comment: Is the `*` really useful ? I get the container ID without using it.

Comment: Perhaps the docker binaries do something smart when filtering based on a regex, I don't know that. This is just the way I use it :).