# How to check heap size inside docker container

Tags: docker, jvm, docker-swarm, heap-memory

We are using docker swarm on the server. using openjdk8. If do :

```
docker service ls
```

**see the result :**

```
ID                  NAME                               MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                                PORTS
7l89205dje61        integration_api                          replicated          1/1                 docker.repo1.tomba.com/koppu/koppu-api:3.1.2.96019dc
.................
```

**I am trying to update jvm heap size for this service so I tried :**

```
docker service update --env-add JAVA_OPTS="-Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" integration_api
```

**Saw this result:**

```
integration_api
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
```

**Now I am trying to see the heap size and not finding a way as when tried to get inside the container taking the id above as :**

```
docker exec -it 7l89205dje61 bash
```

getting error :

```
this container does not exit.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can exec into the running container and display the current heap size with something like this?

```
# get the name of a container within your service with
docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> bash

# after execing into the container,
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

[Use this Stack Orerflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966724/shell-into-swarm-container) to figure out how to exec into a service

Got the java code to print heap settings from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797560/command-line-tool-to-find-java-heap-size-and-memory-used-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Note these ideas don't have a good example out there as yet to my knowledge.  However, one good way of doing it is to implement a "healthcheck" process that would query the JVM statistics like heap and other things and report it to another system.

Another way is exposing the [Spring Boot Actuator API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) so that Prometheus can read and track it over time.